# Something like Merb Parts in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, widget, merb, rails-cells

Is there anything like [Merb Parts](http://wiki.merbivore.com/howto/parts) in Rails 3 out there now?

I've seen [Rails Cells](http://cells.rubyforge.org/download.html), but felt like [nobody was using them](http://yehudakatz.com/2007/09/06/merbs-parts-are-pretty-rocking-too/).

What are your thoughts?  Are these suitable for widgets?

Comment: I am usings cells, and I believe it's a good way for parts in rails. How come you believe nobody is using it?

Comment: I got the impression no one was using them as well. Maybe if there were a mailing list for users, I could change my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cells, they're around for Rails 3: http://nicksda.apotomo.de/2010/09/cells-for-rails-3-is-stable/

For your convenience there are hundreds of cells users out there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this github repo: http://github.com/drogus/rails-parts